# Remove all previous versions of files in a directory in a Git Repo

Tags: git

I have a lot of large assets in my git repo that I want to remove all previous-revisions and deleted files from the repo. But it needs to keep the most recent copy of the files in that directory.

So far I have only seen how tos that scrubbed previously deleted files and not necessary keep the recent revision.

Comment: Remember that git commits complete file-trees, not changes.  Hence "remove all but current version" is basically the same operation as "remove all versions", applied only to commits that do not contain the current version.  You just need to decide whether to find the "newest" commit that has an "old" version, or just remove it from every commit except the most recent.

Answer (score 1):

Its simpler than that. Just delete the .git folder at root. create a new repository and check in. Also please note that, version control's job is retaining all previous versions, not deleting those.

Answer (score 0):

You are using git for file storage, which is not what it's intended for.

If you don't care for the change history, simply create a `tar.gz` file (or any suitable archive/compress method) containing your large assets, and reference it from your git repo, perhaps with a script or Makefile which copies it and unpacks it to the right place.

As far as removing a file from history entirely (including the current version!), there are two steps:

1. Remove the file from all commits: `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch FILENAME_WITH_PATH' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`
2. Cleanup/purge the repository of the file objects: `rm -rf .git/refs/original/; git reflog expire --expire=now --all; git gc --prune=now; git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

If you are working with a remote repo and need to clean it up as well, `push -f` may not be enough; you will need to re-create it from scratch and push your local (cleaned) copy to it.

Comment: No I'm not, it's an xCode project that has image resources which are updated. You're assuming my purposes instead of looking at my problem. You also gave me a suggestion to do the exact opposite of what I asked.

Comment: How is it the exact opposite? You can remove all occurrences of your asset file(s) from the repo, then re-commit the current version, if you choose so. As far as purposes, even with Xcode projects you can still use correct large file management by splitting which files get committed to the source repository, via e.g. .gitignore, and which files end up in a file repository.